# Oracle 10 g to 11 g migration.. Connection string

Tags: oracle10g, migration, oracle11g, compatibility, jdbc-odbc

I have one query. We are migrating from Oracle 10g to Oracle 11g. In java code we have used jdbc:oracle:oci8:@XYZ for oracle 10g.
But after 11g upgrade, we kept the above code as is. Now i am "**NOT**" facing any issue while connecting to DB during the QA testing. **Its working perfectly fine. We are using JDK 1.5.**

My query is *do i need to change the string to jdbc:oracle:oci:@XYZ
for 11g ?* or existing will work (backward compatibility). Will this cause any problem in future.

Also, what are other things that needs to be taken care from JAVA perspective while migrating to 11g from 10g.

Kindly Advice.

Thanking you.
Gaurav Kalal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connect string does not need to change if the service has the same name.